# Customizing auth0-lock with auth0-angular

Tags: angularjs, auth0

I'm experimenting with auth0-lock from www.auth0.com and AngularJS.
I was able to pass some parameters as in SDK: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/customization#connections-array-

```
        auth.signin({
            disableSignupAction: true,
            socialBigButtons: true,
            //these lines don't work
            //no changes (username, password appears)
            //connection: 'windows-live'
            //this line returns 'No valid connection found'
            //connections: 'windows-live'
            //this line returns 'No valid connection found'
            //connections: ['windows-live']
            //this line doesn't change anything
            //connection: ['windows-live']

        }
```

but I'm not able to pass connections (non angular version from SDK)

```
lock.show({
connections: ['twitter', 'facebook', 'linkedin']
});
```

Both parameters connection or connections don't work.

The problem that I have is that if I don't specify connection (connections) username and password will appear. According to SDK I need to hardcode it, to hide these fields.
As SDK is written for JS not AngularJS, it seems that I have an issue with passing array, or parameter.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You want to send an array with the connections parameter:

```
connections: ['windows-live']
```

Instead of a string like you have:

```
connections: 'windows-live'
```

Comment: I haven't mentioned this, but it doesn't work as well.
 results with: "No Valid Connection Can Be Found"
I have updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the Social in the dashboard?
[image: Enable Social]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems to be so-so on this.  If you use //cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-8.js it should work out of the box as seen in previous response and following the examples https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular/tree/master/examples.

I wrestled with connections: & connection for several hours trying to get some custom connections working.

For you as a base you could enable the various providers in the Auth0 social providers, make sure they toggle green.  Start as simple as possible and expand from there.

```
 auth.signin({
        scope: 'openid name email'
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-8.js"></script>
<!--script src="//cdn.auth0.com/w2/auth0-6.7.js"></script-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.auth0.com/w2/auth0-angular-4.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/a0-angular-storage/dist/angular-storage.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js"></script>
```

login ctrl

```
 .controller('LoginCtrl',
  function onLoginSuccess(profile, token) {
        console.log("login ok");
    }

    function onLoginFailed() {
        console.log("failed login");
    }

    auth.signin({
        scope: 'openid name email'
    }, onLoginSuccess, onLoginFailed);
}
```

config block

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, authProvider,
             jwtInterceptorProvider, $httpProvider) {

authProvider.init({
    domain: '',
    clientID: '',
    loginState: 'login',
    loginUrl: true
});


    authProvider.on('loginSuccess', function($location, profilePromise, idToken, store) {
        profilePromise.then(function(profile) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(profile));
```